# Web Application are being created in Application, Front-end and Distributed Cache Server in SharePoint 2016 Min Role Topology

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, 2016, front-end

Just trying to explore Min Role Topology in **SharePoint 2016**. Services running on my servers

[image]

Now I have noticed that web applications are being created on **Application**, **Front-end** and **Distributed Cache** server and taking the **URL** of **Application** server.

Is that expected or I have missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is expected,

By default when you create the web application and use the default value for port number and host information then it pick the Central Admin server's details and URL will be like this "http://central admin serv:portnumber"

If you want, you have to manually update the host information and AAM.

Comment: I am really expecting you to answer my question. Now please help me to understand few things. **1.** Running services in each server do not match with *MSDN* https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx. **2.** If it is expected, then all web traffic comes to APP server. So to deal with it. Thanks

Comment: is this compliment or :)...I think your farm is not patched with FeaturePack 1(November CU). So thats why you are seeing the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service running on the Distributed Cache Server. after the Nov CU it will not... Other than that it is matching with the MSDN....Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application is responsible to create the IIS on the Server, if this service is running on all servers in the farm then you will see Web application will be created on all servers...So if you dont want your site provision on DC then stop that service or patch it

Comment: Now after creating the Web Application, if you pick the default settings then now you have to update the AAM with the WFE server name but port number will be same....if yow want to create the DNS then point that to the WFE servers( if more then load balancer).SharePoint site access via aam

Comment: You welcome, I am happy now

Comment: Any guide or link can I have for implementing Min Role topology?

Comment: i think, raise another question with your requirement...see what everybody recommend in your sitution. pick the best one. its really hard to get the answer from other people in comment section

Comment: Sorry for asking you too many question. asking another

Comment: No need to say sorry, i am just want your question reach to broader audeince